# Vue quaser production build "A web page is slowing down your browser"

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm building a web application with Vue and Quaser. My development environment works fine and everything loads as it should. I serve the development like any other:

```sh
npm run serve
```

However, on a build, the application takes a lot of resources and freezes the browser. I get the message **"A web page is slowing down your browser"** on firefox while chrome based browsers simply take a lot of time.

```
npm run build
serve -s dist
```

I used `serve -s dist` to test wh netlify was not loading locally. I cannot seem to get why this happens. My package.json looks is as below:

```json
{
  "name": "friendly-chainsaw-sass-kit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.26.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-apexcharts": "^1.6.0",
    "vue-css-donut-chart": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-quasar": "~3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {},
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
          "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"
        ],
        "env": {
          "jest": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest"
  }
}
```

Is there something I might be doing wrong?

Comment: it doesn't build or is there a resource that takes a lot of space? Have you tried doing a profile of the web? check if there is a memory leak somewhere

Comment: @larizzatg, it builds. It just doesn't render as expected and with the speed, it needs to. IN terms of memory leaks, I cannot get the section that eats off that amount of memory from the app being served. Given it's an SPA with no remote calls (everything being grabbed from JSON data objects), shouldn't it have less chances of this?

Comment: It depends, sometimes you can run into race conditions or weird endless loops depending on how you're code is structured, can you append the profile of your page?

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems
https://vuedose.tips/measure-runtime-performance-in-vue-js-apps/

Comment: You're right @larizzatg, I've seen the endless loop in one of my components. Check the answer I'm updating in a few?

Answer (score 1):

As @larizzatg alluded, the error from such a message came from a race condition, just that there was no clear concise error message or direction I could get to from the pop-up. In one of my components, I had a for loop, wherein I was slicing.

```
<div v-for="task in allTasks.splice(0,3)" :key="task.name">
```

The above would have looped through the array of tasks, just not all of them, 3 items to be exact. It works fine in development. However, to get around the error.

```
<div v-for="task in topTasks" :key="task.name">
```

Where `topTasks` comes from a `computed` property. This should have just failed during the development phase other than giving hope it works. I have done the same implementation with Angular-based applications just fine. I hadn't thought it would be an issue with Vue. Makes you go through your previous code implementations to wonder.